# How is fuzzy velvet-like surface on plastic achieved?

Tags: materials, material-science, plastic

This kind:

[image: rabbit with short fuzz coating]

It's a very thin layer of very short (<1mm) hairs, coating a hard plastic underneath. I encounter this sort of lining on some mid-tier electronics that pretend to be more classy than they are, measurement tools boxes, higher (but not top) tier ballpoint boxes, and toys made of rigid plastic. In particular, I remember as a kid, the coating would rub off of more exposed parts, revealing bare plastic of a different color underneath, but there was no layer of cloth, glue or such visible - the "fuzz" seemed to be applied directly to the plastic surface.

What is this surface finish called, and how is it achieved? Where to look if I want to make my own?

Comment: google `flocking`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called flocking and involves a way of mixing chopped fibers into a liquid which is then applied to the surface either by spray or by brush. when the solvents in the paint evaporate, the fibers are left glued to the surface.

Comment: some variations are applied by static electricity